# Paralellogram with text inside

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a parallelogram which has information inside it and at the bottom of it.

Here's a quick overview of what i'm trying to make:
TEAM1

Vs.
TEAM2

I've tried using this but was having trouble with positioning and text being under the actual parallelogram.

```
width: 150px;
height: 100px;
-webkit-transform: skew(20deg);
-moz-transform: skew(20deg);
-o-transform: skew(20deg);
```

So my question is, how would I implement this? I want the text to be on top of the parallelogram and laid out in 3 lines.

Comment: make a container `div`, a background `div` for the parallelogram, and a `span` with the text content. Then use absolute positioning to stack the elements in the desired output.

Comment: Please provide a JSfiddle or CodePen to have a starting point. See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: We have no way of knowing what this is *supposed*  to look like.

Comment: Thanks a bunch magreenberg! Sorted my problem out! :)

Answer (score 0):

"make a container div, a background div for the parallelogram, and a span with the text content. Then use absolute positioning to stack the elements in the desired output." – magreenberg

This is all the stuff if you want to remake this:
 HTML:

```
    <div class="match">
                <div class=parallelogram>
                    <span id="team1">#TEAM1</span><br>
                    <span id="vs">vs.</span><br>
                    <span id="team2">#TEAM2</span><br>
                </div>
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
    section article .matchbg {
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
margin-left: 30px;
margin-right: 30px;
-webkit-transform: skew(-20deg);
-moz-transform: skew(-20deg);
-o-transform: skew(-20deg);
background-color: #ff2828;
position: absolute;
}

section article .matchbg span {
font-family: 'Roboto Condensed:300', sans-serif;
}
#team1 {
font-family: 'Roboto Condensed:700italic', sans-serif;
font-size: 24;
margin-left:25;
}

#team2 {
font-family: 'Roboto Condensed:700italic', sans-serif;
font-size: 24;
margin-left:25;
}

#vs {
font-family: 'Roboto Condensed:700italic', sans-serif;
font-size: 20;
margin-left:60;
}
```

This is just copied and pasted from my .css file, you can do whatever with this.

Answer (score -2):

For the greatest generality use html5 canvas tag with javascript.

Will post link example in a minute.

Comment: Personally don't know javascript, yet. Going to learn it at a later date. Thanks for the reply & suggestion, though.